# Combine unique ID with prediction results to csv pandas python Modelling

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing modelling lets say logistic regression and need to save the results in a dataframe (prediction results and a unique ID).

Code for predictions

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions=lr_clf.predict(test_data)
```

I want that along with predictions, I should also have in a column a unique identifier from X_train in the predictions dataframe (right now predictions is a numpy array). Lets say the unique ID is `ID` column in X_train.

Expected output

```
predictions  ID
11           1000
123          1001
and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the unique ID from X_train along with the predictions as below.

```
#Modelling    
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions=lr_clf.predict(test_data)


#Add ID along with prediction and save the pandas dataframe
 predictions_df=pd.DataFrame(data={"ID":X_train["ID"],"Predictions":predictions})
 predictions_df.to_csv(path="predictions_df.csv",index=False,quoting=3,sep=';')
```